# What is the wrong point of my insertion sort sample program

Tags: c

While I practice `C`,I developed sample `insertion sort` in `C`. after some search and refer some materials ,I wrote following one. After that,I build and run.

```
gcc insertion.c
./a.out
```

But it didn't show anything. What is the wrong point of that? As I am completely beginner,if someone notice important point. will you please let me know.

```
#include<stdio.h>
// show element in each array
void trace(int A[], int N){
 int i;
 for (i =0; i<N; i++){
     if(i>0) printf(" ");
     printf("%d",A[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}

// insertion sort
void insertionSort(int A[],int N){
    int j,i,v;
    for(i=1;i<N;i++){
        v = A[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while( j > 0 && A[j] > v){
            A[j + 1] = A[j];
            j--;
        }
        A[j+1]=v;
        trace(A,N);
    }
}

int main(){
    int N, i, j;
    int A[100];

    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++) scanf("%d", &A[i]);

    trace(A,N);
    insertionSort(A,N);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't see anything because the program is waiting for input - `scanf` blocks the program until the user enters something.

```
int main()
{
    int N, i, j;
    int A[100];
    printf("Enter N: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (i = 0;i < N;i++){
        printf("Enter %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d", &A[i]);
    } 

    trace(A,N);
    insertionSort(A,N);
    return 0;
}
```

Try the above code. If I understand you correctly, you are trying to sort an array. It works, but then shows you different things that may be isn't well.

I hope I've helped.